# Delete values returned by function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function that gets a `PTC_ID` and displays `PTC_ID` and the `PTC` name and all values linked to that `PTC_ID` as `PTC_PTCID`. As shown in picture.

[image]

So I want to have a stored procedure, I think I would need a Temp table that deletes if a `PTC_ID` is entered. It should delete in this case `PTC_ID` which is `10609` and all `PTC_PTC_ID` also with `10609`

Comment: The picture is not visible as expected.

Comment: Wow, ok let me try again. thanks @Akshinthalaసాయికళ్యాణ్

Comment: Better?@Akshinthalaసాయికళ్యాణ్

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, the solution is

```
DELETE TABLE_NAME
FROM TABLE_NAME A
INNER JOIN FUNCTION_NAME B
   ON A.PTC_CD = B.PTC_CD
   OR A.PTC_PTCID = B.PTC_CD
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the table, this is just data extracted from a table with a function. I want to delete the data that the function returns

Comment: That is what this query does. To delete table use the command `DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME`

Comment: sorry I read your answer wrong, So then I don't have to make a temp table execute a function into that and then delete from there, sorry I always make small things complex

Comment: No problem friend. It will work. No need of temp table. You could start trying like `DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE PTC_CD = 10069 OR PTC_PTCID = 10069` before using function. You mean a funtion in SQL SERVER right?

Comment: I know your query is not wrong, but I get this error `Parameters were not supplied for the function 'fx_GetProtocolStructureCTE_dec` where do I supply the `PTC_ID`, and yes I have a function in SQL Server

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46806/discussion-between-nizam-and-theuser)

Comment: in my stored proc I have not called it yet, I've never worked with functions that's why I struggle.